# Spring JDBC & Oracle NVarchar : utf8 bug

Tags: java, jdbc, oracle11g, spring-jdbc

I try to insert an UTF8 char into a NVarchar column

**Works parameter jvm :**

```
-Ddefault.nvarchar=true
```

this parameter can not work in production because we have index on nvarchar column (and the application is too slow)

**Works (Java/JDBC) :**

```
dbConnection = ds.getConnection();
preparedStatement = dbConnection.prepareStatement(insertStmt);
preparedStatement.setNString(i++, user.getFirstName());
```

Data are correcte in database

**Not Works (Spring) :**

```
final MapSqlParameterSource map = new MapSqlParameterSource();
map.addValue("firstName", user.getFirstName(), Types.NVARCHAR);
this.jdbcTemplate.update(insertStmt, map);
```

org.springframework.jdbc.UncategorizedSQLException: PreparedStatementCallback; uncategorized SQLException for SQL [ SQL state [99999]; error code [17004]; Type de colonne non valide; nested exception is java.sql.SQLException: Type de colonne non valide

**Not works (Spring Beans) :**

```
final SqlParameterSource params = new BeanPropertySqlParameterSource(user);
this.jdbcTemplate.update(insertStmt, params);
```

*I want use Spring jdbc and set a nvarchar value.
Thanks*